# Using elisp local variables instead of global variables to add a function into a mode-hook

Tags: emacs, elisp, let

So I'm trying to add something into some elisp mode hooks — specifically, I'd like to define a hook's `prettify-symbols-alist` and then specifically activate it by calling `prettify-symbols-mode`.

In any case, I'm getting `org-babel` to export the values into a pair of lists from a table, using `pairlis` to tie them together as an alist, and `add-hook` it into the desired mode using a anonymous function.

So, the thing is, right now if I use a global variable, like the following, it works:

```
(let ((token (quote ("not" "*" "/" "->" "map" "/=" "<=" ">=" "lambda")))
      (code (quote (172 215 247 8594 8614 8800 8804 8805 955)))) ; Generated automatically using org-babel

  (require 'cl)

  (setq *globalvar (pairlis token code))

  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
               (setq prettify-symbols-alist *globalvar)
               (prettify-symbols-mode 1))))
```

But if I try to not use a global variable, by doing it this way, it doesn't work:

```
(let ((token (quote ("not" "*" "/" "->" "map" "/=" "<=" ">=" "lambda")))
      (code (quote (172 215 247 8594 8614 8800 8804 8805 955)))) ; Generated automatically using org-babel
  (let (localv)
    (require 'cl)

    (setq localv (pairlis token code))

    (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
              (lambda ()
                 (setq prettify-symbols-alist localv)
                 (prettify-symbols-mode 1))))
```

I kind of know why: if I `C-h v emacs-lisp-mode-hook`, I'll see that it refers to whatever variable I used in the `let` form, which works when the variable exists, as in `*globalvar`, but not when I use `localvar`, which no longer exists outside of its `let` form. But I'm not sure how to force evaluation of the local variable itself, as I'm still struggling with a lot of concepts in elisp that aren't immediately clear to me.

What am I missing? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Set `lexical-binding` to non-`nil`, or `localv` will be a free variable in your hook function. Preferably, set `lexical-binding` as a file-local variable.

Comment: tariqk: You want to do some reading about dynamic binding vs lexical binding. Dynamic binding is the default, in which case your `let`-bound `localv` variable *is* bound (to no avail) while your `lambda` form is being *defined*, but is no longer bound when that function executes at some point later on. You're expecting a lexical closure, which you'll only get if you enable lexical binding for the library.

Comment: Also, don't quote `'(lambda ...)` like that. See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3595/454

Comment: @Drew: I can try to set `lexical-binding` to a non-`nil` value, but I'm trying to figure out how to do that with `org-babel`, since this is basically an org file that gets tangled into an emacs lisp file. Unfortunately, [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html) page is saying that it should be set as the first line (presumably `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-`?), but… I can't seem to find out how to ensure that happens.

Comment: @phils re: using `'(lambda ...)`, I was *initially* planning to use `(defun ...)` and define a function that would take both the hook and the alist to use, but I never could get it to work properly. I ended up using `'(lambda ...)` because it worked at the time, but I'm beginning to suspect that I might need to relook at the `(defun ...)` again.

Comment: Maybe just use `lexical-let` then -- that predates the introduction of `lexical-binding`, and works without it.

Comment: @phils Well, I've used `lexical-let` and it finally solves the problem I was having. Using `(lambda ...)` without the quote appears to work as well. Now I'm beginning to wonder why I put it in. Huh. Might be a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's what I did in the end:

```
(let ((token (quote ("not" "*" "/" "->" "map" "/=" "<=" ">=" "lambda")))
      (code (quote (172 215 247 8594 8614 8800 8804 8805 955))))
  (require 'cl)

  (lexical-let (localv)
    (setq localv (pairlis token code))
    (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
               (lambda ()
                  (setq prettify-symbols-alist localv)
                  (prettify-symbols-mode 1)))))
```

I ended up using [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils)' suggestion to use `lexical-let` rather than [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729907/drew)'s suggestion mostly because I'm currently using `org-babel` to tangle code blocks into my source code (basically I'm using `org-mode` to organize my setting files), and there doesn't appear to be a way to set the `lexical-binding` file-local variable — according to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html) page, you need to set it as the first line (using `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-`), and I can't find a way to do that yet.

In any case, thank you to everyone who helped me out on this question!

Answer (score 1):

Start by setting `lexical-binding` to non-`nil`, or else `localv` will be a free variable in your hook function. Preferably, set `lexical-binding` as a file-local variable.

In addition, there is nothing in your code that makes `localv` **buffer-local**. Presumably you want to give it a value that is local to the buffer that is in that mode. The code that binds it should be evaluated in the mode (i.e., in the buffer) in question.

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding what you mean by making `localv` buffer-local, and why, because from my understanding both `prettify-symbol-mode` and `prettify-symbol-alist` are already buffer-local, and `localv` is just at this point a placeholder.

Comment: Under dynamic binding, the value seen for `localv` when your lambda function *executes* would be the *global* value for that variable -- unless it's buffer-local.

Comment: Well, if I inspect `prettify-symbol-mode` and `prettify-symbol-alist` with `C-h v`, it tells me that both automatically become buffer-local when set. `localv` is nowhere to be found with `C-h v`, when using `lexical-let`, so I don't know if it's relevant any more.

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution. With `lexical-let`, the call to `lambda` (inside `add-hook`) generates a *closure*, as you can see if you type `M-x ielm RET` and `emacs-lisp-mode-hook RET` to examine its value.

You could also use old-school style backtick like this:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
           `(lambda ()
              (setq prettify-symbols-alist ',localv)
              (prettify-symbols-mode 1)))
```

(EDIT)

Note the `backtick` before the `lambda` and (as tarikq mentioned) the `quote-comma` before `localv`.

I think you got the meaning!

Actually, instead of "expand this then quote it", I would say "insert its value (from the lexical environment), then quote it".

If you try something like:

```
 (macroexpand '`(lambda ()
                  (setq prettify-symbols-alist ',localv)
                  (prettify-symbols-mode 1)))
```

then you will get what lisp will actually do at run time:

```
 (cons 'lambda
      (cons nil
            (cons
             (list 'setq 'prettify-symbols-alist (list 'quote localv))
             '((prettify-symbols-mode 1)))))
```

and you will see how the whole list is constructed, and how `localv` is *normally* evaluated, i.e. not quoted (compare with the symbols `'setq` and `'prettify-symbols-alist` and the list `'((prettify-symbols-mode 1))`)

Comment: I'm actually noticing the quote followed by the comma. The backtick means "quote this except everything with a comma in front of it", and the quote-comma means "expand this then quote it", right?